# Show the cached webpage when visited on even number visit, fetch on odd number visit in front-end

Tags: javascript, apache, caching, browser

I'm developing a website. **For some performance reason, I want to cache the webpage when the user visited first time and to show the same cache data when visited again. But if the same user visited the page one more time(3rd time) again. I want to show newly fetched content from sever.**

While using Twitter and Facebook. I have noticed that they are showing the cached data when I visit the previously visited pages. But When try to visit the page again. They fetch data from the server.

Can anyone know-what Facebook and twitter does. Or anyone knows what is the architecture behind it.

I don't want to cache the page in the server or using Memcache. I want it to do on front-end or by the browser or by the headers.

**Clear explanation:**

let take example **https://example.com** website.

if I visit the page for the first time. It has to be cached.

If I visit the same page again. the page has to show from cache.

If I visit the same page again. The webpage needs to be fetched from data.

Don't suggest me a Service worker or PWA thing. Service worker only caches the data which was sent from the server.

**what I need is, the webpage should be cached after the addition/manipulation of DOM in my page.**

**Is there any way I could achieve this via apache or by the browser or by javascript?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Functionality I want, like in this video?

Youtube Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWE_JzWs_No&feature=youtu.be

Functionality Description : When the user click back button. I want to go to the previous page with the state(up-to they scrolled) where they left.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by this 
"what I need is, the webpage should be cached after the addition/manipulation of DOM in my page."
Are you expecting the page state ( example an opened menu) to be retained? 

If not, you should be able to fetch the page from the server by setting up a `max-age` in headers

Comment: Hi Ramakay, thanks for your reply. Actually, I'm using pagination on my page. I'm appending data in the page by fetching data in ajax request. I simply need the whole fetched HTML content should be there when I visit that page again.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of is to use persistent storage in your browser, maybe IndexDB. You can store the `visit count` here. On the basis of `visit count` you can either send back the cache response from service worker in even request or store the fetch and update cache on service worker in odd request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nikhil.**I have tried this solution with the service worker already**.  I was not able to solve in service worker cache. In service worker, I can cache the webpage which was sent from the server. But my page gets changed with additional DOM content during pagination in the scroll event. My actual problem which I want solution is when I go back to the same page. I need to scroll the page where the user left in that page(Like we can see on Twitter and Facebook). I have tried it with history.back() function in browser. But that solution won't give a proper solution I want.

Comment: It's hard for me to answer like this. Can you please update the question and share what you have done.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I have added the video link and also described what functionality I actually need.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the question and the clarifying comment

> Actually, I'm using pagination on my page. I'm appending data in the page by fetching data in ajax request. I simply need the whole fetched HTML content should be there when I visit that page again.

Your best bet is to use localstorage, each time you fetch the page requested by the user set it to the localstorage with a identifier on what that page is. This way you will have *snapshots* of the page stored along with url identifiers.

So, in the following flow.

1. User visits your landing page.
2. *They* scroll and fetch page 2
3. Try to store the url identifier, e.g:`/page2` via `history.pushState` or `#page2`
4. Write a key with the url and the state of the page
5. Now when the page is loaded, check for the hash or path and load the corresponding limit.

*Caveats*

1. Localstorage maxes out between 5-10mb but if your results are in JSON, you could store more *snapshots*
2. Restoring scroll behavior to exact position to dock is another challenge you will get into, this can be done by noting the scroll position and restoring it.
3. A lot comes down to what you are fetching, e.g: if you play inline videos like Twitter that autoplay, you may have to re-issue those events.

**Final word**

If you can, choose a library that handles some of this behavior - You can see an example here https://infinite-scroll.com/demo/full-page/page5.html - Keep scrolling and you will see *pagexx.html* changing in your browser - This means the back button has a unique identifier to restore to.